# Custom Post Types and Child Themes!

Tags: custom-post-types, child-theme, theme-customizer

OK here is my question....

I have a professionally purchased theme that has a custom post type of "PortFolio" built into the theme.

The post type is ideal for what i'm trying to achieve in the website project but I wish to rename the actual post type to "Services" instead of "Portfolio". At the same time im planning to remove some of the fields in the post type but to also change the layout of the actual page too.

Within the theme itself there has been a lot of custom modifications, and what im worried about is that if I change any of these settings, when it comes around to updating the theme, I presume the settings will be overwritten??

I have setup a child theme for this project, and wanted to know if I make any changes to the functions within the child theme, when I eventually update the theme, will the function updates change too?

I know this may be a blindingly obvious question, but whats the best way to achieve this?

Regards
Tom

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The problem I can see is that the author of the theme is updating the theme at least once per month with new features and functionality. This is what concerns me!

What do you think the best method for me to do going forward is? Maybe creating a brand new post type?

Thanks again for the reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

In away, if you change basic functionally of the parent theme then you should not use a child theme. Child themes should be used to extend or override functionality but not change it. How can you tell the difference between extending and changing? You can't :(.

In other words, the best place to ask is the author of the theme. It might be that he will never release an update or an update that he will release will introduce incompatibility with your child theme.